# Android Kitkat Webview Plays Only the Sound of the Video

Tags: android, webview, youtube, android-4.4-kitkat, chromium

Before you downgrade I know there are similar questions related to this topic when you google it. Even it had been answered for several times here in Stackoverflow.

Yet although I read all of those topics none of them solved my problem. My code works great for Jelly Bean, lollipop and marshmallow variations. Only for kitkat it is impossible to play a video via webview. For example on Youtube you can hear the audio but you can't see the video at all. *This is also happening in vimeo.*[You can see in this screenshot from emulator. I can actually listen the audio but cannot see the video.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQE1A.jpg)

I know with 4.4.4 Webview started using chromium. I know I should add this: `mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){});` Also I should add `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` to my manifest file. However when accelaration is false video never loads. If I add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` This time audio comes but video doesn't appear.

At last I am still unable to play videos. If you could help me with this I will very much appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

**If it helps these are some of the error logs:**

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(5942)] [.Compositor-Onscreen-0xb8bb47f8]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glUseProgram: program not linked

E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(5718)] [.Compositor-Onscreen-0xb8bb47f8]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glUniformMatrix4fv: wrong uniform function for type
```

Comment: Guys please no one knows the solution for this issue? I see many topics related to this problem and none of them answered properly.

Comment: Works for me. Samsung Galaxy S4, 4.4.4. Maybe it's just the emulator. Did you test it on a device?

Comment: @MikeM. Frankly, I couldn't test it on an actual device. I only tried on Genymotion's and Android Studio's stock virtual devices. In fact it came to my mind but after I tested it on several different emulators I thought it would also not work on real devices. Thank you for your answer! It might be an emulator problem. I will try to find a real device and test it as soon as possible. But one last question. Did you try a code sample close to mine above while testing it on S4? I am also suspecting my coding may be faulty at some point.

Comment: Yep, pretty much. I have a stub project for testing WebView stuff, and I just changed all the settings and client overrides to what you've got. I couldn't get it to not work, and I tried several ways to make it fail. I thought it'd at least flake with an SSL error, but even if I remove the `onReceivedSslError()` override, it still works.

Comment: @MikeM. Allright then and thanks once again. I will find a device runs on kitkat an test it right away!

Answer (score 0):

Set software Accelerated in webview activity, 
mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Comment: No remove that line in mainfest and set the abovw code whith the webview setting after you call it. Ps mWebView change it to your webview name

Comment: Firstly thank you for your answer. Secondly, I in fact tried this before. If I add this code in webview activity video never loads.

Comment: Error logs disappears though video won't play, won't load.

Comment: It has been a long time since i faced this problem so please try NONE insted of SOFTWAER

Comment: Also set enabel javascript

Comment: This time it circles back to the first state. You can hear the audio but there's no video. Also same logs appear as I typed above. It seems like the video goes out of the screen. It's like in the screenshot which I also linked above. I really don't understand why is this happening.

Comment: If you mean webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); I'm afraid Javascript is already enabled.

Comment: Last try and i pull out :D use layer type HARDWARE i really fixed before by this methode

Comment: Well unfortunately it has no effect neither :D In fact adding codes about the layer had no effect so far. Only setting android:hardwareAccelerated="" true or false changes the result. I typed all setLayerType() codes you said with accelerated true and false yet it didn't solve the problem. Is there anything else comes to your mind :D

Comment: You dont have to put acceleter maybe that affect?! Anny way i will post my setting when the pwoer comes

Comment: Now i saw it retry without mainfest line and replace null with paint #also add this before load url wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
});

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand "replace null with paint#" part.

Comment: Sorry bussy coding, i ment this :

Comment: mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paint);

Comment: Now I could test it but it says " Cannot resolve symbol 'paint' "